# select records that don't have certain values in 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select some rows that don't have certain values in 2 columns.  Currently I am doing this for a single column by doing the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE    (ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID)
    AND ItemID NOT IN(
        SELECT ItemID FROM UpdateMyTable WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID
    )
```

But now I need to filter out rows that don't contain 2 column values at the same time: ItemID and ChildItemID

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post your table schemas? I'm not having the easiest time understanding what you're asking.

Comment: how about using NULL to check for empty values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTable                                 AS data
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT x, y, z FROM UpdateMyTable)     AS check
    ON  data.x = check.x
    AND data.y = check.y
    AND data.z = check.z
WHERE
  x = @x
  AND check.x IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTable                                 AS data
WHERE
  x = @x
  AND NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT
                    *
                  FROM
                    UpdateMyTable        AS check
                  WHERE
                      data.x = check.x
                  AND data.y = check.y
                  AND data.z = check.z
                 )
```

Comment: I'm not sure if SQLServer will automatically provide this optimization, but you _may_ get index-only access in the subquery by changing the `SELECT *` to something like `SELECT '1'` (so long as `x`, `y`, and `z` are indexed appropriately) - the query would then not be accessing the entire record.

Comment: This is not an issue in SQL Server.

Comment: I have to use the LEFT JOIN because I will be using these records to do and update on the records using an EXISTS version of this - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a JOIN instead of a NOT IN.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN UpdateMyTable u ON t.ManufacturerId = u.ManufacturerId
WHERE t.ManufacturerId = @ManufacturerId
AND t.ItemId != u.ItemId
AND t.ItemId != u.ChildItemId
```

Comment: Besides being counter-intuitive (`INNER JOIN` - so we're including these rows, right?), this has the effect of excluding rows when _either_ condition matches, not _both_.

Comment: Additionally, for every row in `ManufactureId`, there will be many rows that don't match in `UpdateMyTable`.  This means that far from excluding any records, it will create a 1:many join and massively duplicate Every record.